# parsing xml w/ multiple images to html

Tags: html, xml, parsing

I am having an issue on how to parse multiple images using xml. The error I am getting is that it is repeating all the image data in one img.

```
$(document).find('slider > image').each(function(){ 
          var img = $(document).find("slider > image > src").text();
          var desc = $(document).find("slider > image > description").text();
          $("<img src='"+img+"' alt='"+desc+"' />").appendTo('slider');
});
```

For example.

```
<img alt="The Last of usGTA VMirror Edge" src="assets/images/fullimage1.jpgassets/images/fullimage2.jpgassets/images/fullimage3.jpg">
<img alt="The Last of usGTA VMirror Edge" src="assets/images/fullimage1.jpgassets/images/fullimage2.jpgassets/images/fullimage3.jpg">
<img alt="The Last of usGTA VMirror Edge" src="assets/images/fullimage1.jpgassets/images/fullimage2.jpgassets/images/fullimage3.jpg">
```

Here is the xml syntax

```
<carousal>
        <slider>        
            <image>
                <src>assets/images/fullimage1.jpg</src>
                <description>The Last of us</description>
            </image>           
            <image>
                <src>assets/images/fullimage2.jpg</src>
                <description>GTA V</description>
            </image>           
            <image>
                <src>assets/images/fullimage3.jpg</src>
                <description>Mirror Edge</description>
            </image>             
        </slider>
</carousal>
```

Here is the html

```
<slider></slider>
```